# gmtime returning incorrect hour

Tags: c++, c, time

I am retrieving the GMT time in c++/c. But its returning the incorrect hour. For example right now the hour should be 9am but the `struct tm` object returns 3am. Any idea why or what I am doing wrong?

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm* ptm;
time(&rawtime);
ptm = gmtime(&rawtime);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << ptm->tm_hour; // outputs "3" when it should be "9"
```

gmtime should always return the UTC/GMT time regardless of where the user is or what timezone setting they have right?

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://ideone.com/K9116G

Comment: I tried and I think it seems good, [ideone](https://ideone.com/uJPX0k)

Comment: Some users used to keep their computers in utc and instead set the time to local time. Can you verify if you're on the gmt you think you are?

Comment: What is "c++/c"? This looks like (unidiomatic) C++ to me. C does not have `std::stringstream`. And what's wrong with `std::chrono`?

Answer (score 1):

> gmtime should always return the UTC/GMT time regardless of where the user is or what timezone setting they have right?

Yes, as long as their computer clock is set correctly.

Evidently yours is not.